# What is the song when Sakura sees Naruto's fox form in "Naruto Shippuden" episode 43?

Tags: naruto, music

In episode 43 of *Naruto Shippuden*, there is a song that is not included (I think) in any of the OSTs. When Naruto

> is stabbed by Orochimaru's long sword and

crashes onto rocks, this song plays when Sakura sees Naruto's fox form.

---

Also, that song or a similar one can be heard in episode 166 when

> Hinata is stabbed by Pain

which makes Naruto rages

---

I think it can also be heard in episode 258 or 259 when

> Kisame got interrogated and they almost learned who the guy who calls himself "Uchiha Madara" is.

Comment: Have you tried listening through the soundtrack? What about music recognition apps?

Comment: I listened OSTs and couldnt find it I googled it and I found that some other people asked this question about 1 year ago and those who answered them said that that song isnt in the OST but I will try to find it via listening OST again.

Comment: try music recognition apps then

Answer (score 0):

The track that plays in E43 around 03:08 is called "Tragic".

Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54U3fnY2uEI

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of slow, ominous track that I mainly recognize from the Kisame interrogation scene at turtle island, during the flashback where Kisame meets Madara for the first time.

> Madara: "Then I shall release you from the pain of those falsehoods."
>  Kisame: "Who are you?"
>  Madara: "First, we'll start with this nation. You have toiled to dispose of your comrades up until now. From now on, work with me as my comrade."

It sounds like Dark Clouds (Shippuuden OST 1 track 20), but with the higher frequency strings instrument removed.

There's an unofficial fan-spliced version of this variant [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK5Bl-n0EUk), titled "Dark Clouds (other Verison)".

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be Shippuu Kumikyoku (Hurricane Suite). During the scene where Yamato uses Elder Jutsu to suppress the chakra of the nine-tailed fox, that's around 4 min in the video.
You can find it on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5Hp42y7gVA&list=PL4C928EAF7AA5B906&index=28

Answer (score -2):

It's *Despair*, the 19th track of *Naruto Shippūden: Original Soundtrack* ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkbQ71K3n1M))